# Xcode and/or the iPhone simulator is getting my targets confused

Tags: xcode

I have an Xcode project with four targets.  Two of them are called "Unit Converter" and "Math Reference."  I can reproducibly do the following:

1. Clean all targets in Xcode.  Reset my simulator.
2. Set the Xcode project to the "Math Reference" target.
3. Build and Debug.
   RESULT: Math reference program launches in the simulator.  When I suspend the program by hitting the home button on the simulator, the icon for the math reference is shown on the simulator.  If I click on that icon, the math reference re-launches.  So far, so good.
4. Set the Xcode project to the "Unit Converter target."
5. Build and Debug.
   RESULT:  Unit converter program launches in the simulator.  When I suspend the program by hitting the home button on the simulator, there is no icon for the unit converter.  However, clicking on the math reference icon starts up the unit converter.
6. Repeat steps 1-3.
   RESULT: same as before.
7. Stop the active task, then clean all targets in the simulator.
8. Set the Xcode project to the "Unit Converter" Target.
9. Build and Debug.
   RESULT:  Math reference program launches in the simulator.  When I suspend the program by hitting the simulator's home button, the unit converter and math reference icons are both visible on the simulator.  And clicking on each icon starts the appropriate program.

The upshot is that regardless of whether or not I clean before switching to the second target, Xcode and/or the simulator gets confused.  However, as detailed in the results of steps 5 and 9, the manner of this confusion depends on whether or not I clean.

Can anyone explain what is going on and/or what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that they both had the same "Product Name".

This is found in the info panel for the target, under packaging.